# From MongoDB to Pyspark DataFrame

Tags: python, json, mongodb, csv, pyspark

I would love your opinion on my proceeding. Please note that I am more interested in the mindflow than the actual code, since I am new to Spark and related techs.

1. I have a mongodb collection, named *users*:

   ```
    db.users.findOne();
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("578ffa8e7eb9513f4f55a935"),
        "user_name" : "koteras",
        "retweet_count" : 0,
        "tweet_followers_count" : 461,
        "source" : "web_address",
        "coordinates" : null,
        "tweet_mentioned_count" : 1,
        "tweet_ID" : "755891629932675072",
        "tweet_text" : "RT @ochocinco: I beat them all for 10 straight hours #FIFA16KING",
        "user" : {
            "CreatedAt" : ISODate("2011-12-27T09:04:01Z"),
            "FavouritesCount" : 5223,
            "FollowersCount" : 461,
            "FriendsCount" : 619,
            "UserId" : 447818090,
            "Location" : "501"
        }
    }
   ```
2. Because it is quite common that a company may require it, I made a conversion to CSV:

   ```
    ./mongodb/bin/mongoexport --db sample --collection users --out tweets.csv --type=csv --fields _id,user_name,retweet_count,tweet_followers_count,source,coordinates,tweet_mentioned_count,tweet_ID,tweet_text,user.CreatedAt,user.FavouritesCount,user.FollowersCount,user.FriendsCount,user.UserID,user.Location
   ```
3. Now, I would like to make an RDD from it. So I proceeded with:
   3A) Importing the CSV:

   ```
   tweet_lines = sc.textFile('...mypath/mongodb/tweets.csv')
   ```

3B) Create the tuples, and here come my doubt:

```
tweet_tuples = tweet_lines.map(lambda line : line.split(","))
    tweet_tuples.take(2)


[['_id',
       'user_name',
      'retweet_count',
      'tweet_followers_count',
      'source',
      'coordinates',
      'tweet_mentioned_count',
      'tweet_ID',
      'tweet_text',
      'user.CreatedAt',
      'user.FavouritesCount',
      'user.FollowersCount',
      'user.FriendsCount',
      'user.UserID',
      'user.Location'],
     ['ObjectId(578ffa8e7eb9513f4f55a935)',
      'koteras',
      '0',
      '461',
      '"<a href=>Twitter for iPhone</a>"',
      '',
      '1',
      '755891629932675072',
      'RT @ochocinco: I beat them all for 10 straight hours #FIFA16KING  ',
      '2011-12-27T09:04:01.000Z',
      '5223',
      '461',
      '619',
      '',
      '501']]
```

3B) Create the tuples, and here come my doubt:

```
tweet_tuples = tweet_lines.map(lambda line : line.split(","))
```

I tried several separators, but I always got an error when, later, the dataframe is parsed.
For example:

```
header = tweet_lines.first()
schema = StructType([StructField(str(i), StringType(), True) for i in header])
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(tweet_tuples, schema)
df.printSchema()
df.show()
```

I tried several separators, but I always got an error when, later, the dataframe is parsed.
For example:

```
header = tweet_lines.first()
schema = StructType([StructField(str(i), StringType(), True) for i in header])
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(tweet_tuples, schema)
df.printSchema()
df.show()

return

Py4JJavaError 
...Input row doesn't have expected number of values required by the schema. 15 fields are required while 9 values are provided...
```

What do you think I am missing, along the pipeline? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a nested dict with 9 levels, and inside `user` there are 6 fields and that's how it makes 15. So you need to unpack the `user` key to make the rest of the columns. Show the output of `tweet_lines.take(5)`

Comment: @pissall edited. I thought the --field parameter in the mongoexport step would have dealed with the issue. Maybe I was superficial.

Comment: Is your issue solved?